# Alamofire data is not coming instantly for usage

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, completionhandler

when I am getting data from alamofire  it is not yet loaded completely, before that itself my below code is getting executed, i don't know how to use completion handler in it, i am new to iOS programming, anyone please help.

```
func mobileVerification(mobileNumber:String)->Bool{

        let params:[String:String] = ["mobile_num":mobileNumber]
        Alamofire.request("*************",method:.post,parameters:params,encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody).responseJSON { response in

               var loginMessage = ""
                if let jdata = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: jdata, encoding: .utf8) {

                    let json = JSON(data:jdata)
                    print(json)
                    let array = json["result"].arrayValue
                    print(array[0]["message"])

                    if let loginMessage = array[0]["message"].string{
                        self.view.makeToast(loginMessage)
                    }


                }


            }
        if loginMessage == "success"
        {

            //performSegue(withIdentifier: "reg2mobileverification", sender: nil)
            return true
        }
        else
        {
            self.view.makeToast("LoginFailed")
            //print("login Failed")
            return false
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 3.0

This is asynchronous request which can only reruns using completion block method(closure).
You can try this which returns true or false, hope this will help you.

```
func mobileVerification(mobileNumber:String,completion:@escaping(Bool) -> Void) {
   
    let params:[String:String] = ["mobile_num":mobileNumber]
    Alamofire.request("*************",method:.post,parameters:params,encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody).responseJSON { response in
        
        if let jdata = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: jdata, encoding: .utf8) {
            
            let json = JSON(data:jdata)
            print(json)
            let array = json["result"].arrayValue
            print(array[0]["message"])
            
            if let loginMessage = array[0]["message"].string{
                
                if loginMessage == "success"
                {
                    self.view.makeToast(loginMessage)
                    completion(true)
                }
                else
                {
                    self.view.makeToast("LoginFailed")
                    completion(false)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Use of Clouser:-**

```
mobileVerification(mobileNumber: "1234567890") { (result) in
            if result {
               performSegue(withIdentifier: "reg2mobileverification", sender: nil) 
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to process data in closure that you implemented in Alamofire method:

```
Alamofire.request("*************",method:.post,parameters:params,encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody).responseJSON { response in

               var loginMessage = ""
                if let jdata = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: jdata, encoding: .utf8) {
                    // IN THIS BLOCK YOU HAVE TO PROCESS RECEIVED DATA AND IMPLEMENT BUSINESS LOGIC
                    let json = JSON(data:jdata)
                    print(json)
                    let array = json["result"].arrayValue
                    print(array[0]["message"])

                    if let loginMessage = array[0]["message"].string{
                        self.view.makeToast(loginMessage)
                    }


                }


            }
```

This closure will be executed asynchronously when data received.

Comment: I need to implement these statements also if loginMessage == "success"
        {

            //performSegue(withIdentifier: "reg2mobileverification", sender: nil)
            return true
        }
        else
        {
            self.view.makeToast("LoginFailed")
            //print("login Failed")
            return false
        }